# jqgrid MVC omit some columns from ModelState

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid in MVC setup as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url: '/Home/DynamicGridData/',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: ['id', 'note', 'tax', 'PaymentType', 'CreatedByUsername', 'Actions'],
            colModel: [
                  { name: 'id', index: 'id', hidden: true, key: true, editable: true, editrules:{ required:false } },
                  { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 40,align:'center', editable: true, editrules: { required : true } },
                  { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 400, align: 'center', editable: true, editrules: { required : true } },
                  { name: 'PaymentTypeId', index: 'PaymentTypeId', width: 400, align: 'center', editable: true, edittype:"select", 
                    editoptions: { dataUrl: '/Home/PaymentTypes/' }},
                  { name: 'CreatedByUsername', index: 'CreatedByUsername', hidden: true, editable: true, editrules:{ required:false } },
                  { name: 'act',index:'act',width:55,align:'center',sortable:false,formatter:'actions',
                     formatoptions:{
                         keys: true, // we want use [Enter] key to save the row and [Esc] to cancel editing.
                         beforeSubmit:function(postdata, formid) {
                         alert("Hi");
                             jQuery("#ValidationSummary").show('slow');
                         },

                         },}
              ],
            pager: jQuery('#pager'),
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
            sortname: 'Id',
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            imgpath: '',
            caption: 'My first grid',
            editurl: '/Home/Save/'
        });
        jQuery("#list").navGrid('#pager', { edit: false, search: false, add: true });

    }); 
</script>
```

When creating on submit it goes to the save method on the controller.

As you can see `CreatedByUsername` and `id` are hidden for normal view and edit.

When I add new data though I find that `ModelState.IsValid = false.`

I've managed to make it so that `CreatedByUsername` does not added an error to the `ModelState` even though no data is added for it on insert through `editrules:{ required:false }`.

The problem is this same piece of code doesn't work for the `id` and is adding an Error to the `ModelState` of "The id field is required."

Can anyone please tell me how to prevent this from happening for the `id` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your id field has the key attribute and besides your validation rule this field is required. A workaround is to define a custom function for validation an always return true

Answer (score 0):

Can you set the id field in your viewmodel to nullable? Like this:

public int? Id { get; set; }

If the id is not nullable, mvc will automatically create a validation error. If you're not using a viewmodel, but just using parameters on your save action, you can set the id parameter to nullable.